# Azure Application Gateway External URL Rewrite

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

When setting up Azure application gateway external URL redirection, is it possible to rewrite, without changing the URL in browser address bar ?

Comment: What do you expect? Could you describe more details in your question? After setting up App Gateway, you can access the backend pool via Gateway public IP address directly, also, App gateway supports URL-path based routing rules.

Comment: I'm trying to redirect the HTTP request to an external URL. For example, if the app gateway domain name is mydomain.com, when someone access it I want to redirect it to bing.com. It works now. But the URL in the address bar also changes. I want to avoid that show it as mydomain.com in the address bar. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to access the application gateway website (usually xxx.cloudapp.net) or public IP address and redirect to an external website like www.bing.com.

It's impossible that the URL keeps displaying the xxx.cloudapp.net once redirecting to the www.bing.com. Since you have not owned the domain www.bing.com, you can not take control of an external site. Also, you use URL redirection. Certainly, the URL will redirect to another site. If the redirection URL is still the same as the original URL. Then the DNS could not resolve the redirection URL.

[Application Gateway redirect overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-redirect-overview)

Hope this makes sense.