# Azure applicationgateway: How can I rewrite the url so the user still sees user.mysite.net, but application gateway redirects to test.mysite.com/user1

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Can't seem to pin down the correct order of operations here if it exists...

**Current setup:**

I have user.mysite.net pointing at application gateway public ip. test.mysite.com/user1 is pointing at a VM hosting a hello world application. This VM exists in the same tenant but different subscription. The app is just a simple hello world app.

**Target state:**

I want to configure the rewrite or redirection, so that when I hit user.mysite.net in my browser it should send me to test.mysite.com/user1, but at the same time, within the browser I don't want to change the url, I want to preserve the original url: user.mysite.net

Is this possible? If so, how would I even go about configuring it or order operations? i.e what would the rewrite rules look like and then do I attach it to a routing rule with redirection or backend?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a URL rewrite, Application Gateway rewrites the URL before the request is sent to the backend. This will not change what users see in the browser because the changes are hidden from the user.

Please check if you can do pattern matching with the  location header matching eg. IF contains mysite.net  and Perform an action to rewrite the location header  [appGW -rewrite-http-headers-url.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20rewrite%20rule%20with%20a%20condition%20that%20evaluates%20if%20the%20location%20header)

Other wise it may not be possible with rewrite,if it is external site url and the original site has to appear in address bar .See [Reference -Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581692/azure-application-gateway-external-url-rewrite)

> **NOTE**: URL rewrite feature is only available on Application Gateway v2
> SKU. You can follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#rewrite-configuration) to implement rewrite
> URL path.

**Reference:**
[Rewrite URL and query string with Azure Application Gateway - Azure portal | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-url-portal#configure-url-rewrite)